# Retorno array em SQL em uma variável php, para posterior montagem de HTML

Tags: php, sql, ajax, mvc

Preciso fazer uma pesquisa no banco em uma variável data e retornar apenas os Anos. Para isto fiz o seguinte :

**No controle:**

```
public static function getDataAnos() {
    $bd = new Banco(BANCO_HOST, BANCO_USUARIO, BANCO_SENHA, BANCO_BASE_DADOS);

    $sql = "SELECT YEAR (postagens.data) as ano FROM postagens GROUP BY ano";
    return $bd->executarSQL2($sql);
}
```

**Na biblioteca para acessar o Banco:**

```
public function executarSQL2($sql)
{

    $resultado = $this->query($sql);     
    return $resultado->fetch_array();    
}
```

**No controle (disponibiliza ao carregar a página):**

```
$anos = Postagens::getDataAnos();
```

**Na visão:**

```
<?php
  if ($anos !== false) {
      echo "<div id='filtros'>";
      var_dump($anos);
      foreach ($anos as $a) {
          echo "  <input type='radio' name='filtro' value=" . $a. ">" . $a. "<br>";
      }
      echo "</div>";
  }
?>
```

**O PROBLEMA:**

Tenho neste momento no banco 4 datas uma 2011, duas 2015 e uma 2017. O que deveria estar me retornando um array com [0] - 2011, [1] - 2015, [2] - 2017. Mas o var_dumps que coloquei esta mostrando isto:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "2011" ["ano"]=> string(4) "2011" }
```

Já tentei mudar no banco esta linha:

```
return $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQL_NUM);
```

Ai o retorno do var_dumps muda para:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "2011" }
```

Coloquei só as partes do código que achei relevante para o problema, é minha primeira pergunta aqui, espero ter conseguido demonstrar o problema e desde já agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Você está usando o PDO para conectar-se com o banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a função `fetch_array` retorna apenas a proxima linha do resultset retornado na função `query()`. Para retornar todas as linhas do resultset pode-se usar a função [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

```
public function executarSQL2($sql)
{

    $resultado = $this->query($sql);     
    return $resultado->fetch_all();    
}
```

## Recebendo dados na view

Como a função `getDataAnos` retorna um array de duas dimensões o conteudo laço for deve ser modificado para que a variavel `$a` não seja impressa (já que ela representa um vetor). Em fim, da para resolver assim:

```
 echo "  <input type='radio' name='filtro' value=" . $a['ano']. ">" . $a['ano']. "<br>";
```

Comment: Resolveu o problema, muito obrigado!

Mas apareceu um novo problema
No mesmo código da visão anterior o var dumps esta retornado certo: 
    array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "2011" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
    string(4) "2015" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "2017" } }

Mas na hora de mostrar no html ao inves de mostrar os anos esta mostrando apenas ARRAY e o erro:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\TrabBlog\visoes\listar.php on line 50

Comment: editei a resposta.